# F-Regression Feature Selection Using Scipy Sparse Arrays

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, text-mining

I'm trying to do some feature selection on text features for a regression problem. Currently, the training set has ~200K features - way too many. I want to use some of the feature selection tools within scikit-learn, but I'm having issues working with scipy sparse matrices, particularly when trying to pass in the `f_regression` scoring function to the `SelectKBest` transformer.

It appears that the `f_regression` scoring function takes as arguments an `X` feature matrix, a `y` response vector, and an optional `center` argument, which is set to True by default. I believe what would solve the problem is if I could pass `f_regression` with `center=False` to the `SelectKBest` transformer, however if I try something like:

```
f_regressor = f_regression(X, y, center=False)
feature_selector = SelectKBest(f_regressor, k=k)
selected_features = feature_selector.fit_transform(X, y)
```

I get an error stating that the scoring function is not callable. I'm assuming this is because when I initialize it as `f_regress`, it immediately returns p-values and f-scores for the features.

Further, in the source code for the `SelectKBest` transformer, it doesn't look like the fit function does any checking for this `center` argument, so I don't see any straightforward way to pass this scoring function with `center=False` to the transformer:

```
# Abbreviated from the sklearn source
def fit(self, X, y):
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, ['csr', 'csc'])

    # Error I've been getting when instantiating the f_regressor - not callable
    if not callable(self.score_func):
        raise TypeError("The score function should be a callable, %s (%s) "
                        "was passed."
                        % (self.score_func, type(self.score_func)))

    self._check_params(X, y)

    """Score func gets called here - only on X and y, assuming center=True.
    Maybe some argument checking could happen here in the future?
    Not sure if `center` argument could be passed as attribute via
    the constructor?
    """

    score_func_ret = self.score_func(X, y)
    if isinstance(score_func_ret, (list, tuple)):
        self.scores_, self.pvalues_ = score_func_ret
        self.pvalues_ = np.asarray(self.pvalues_)
    else:
        self.scores_ = score_func_ret
        self.pvalues_ = None

    self.scores_ = np.asarray(self.scores_)

    return self
```

If anyone has a workaround for this in the near future, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: So it works if you pass `f_regression` instead of `f_regressor`?  How about making a cover function or lambda that takes `X,y` but sets `center` as you want it?  Instead of evaluating it, make a new function.

Comment: @hpaulj: thanks for getting me to slow down and think. There is (of course) a totally elegant solution to this - the `functools` library. Thanks for the suggestion of cover/lambda functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment from @hpaul above. Using `functools` library and using the `.partial()` method to override the default arguments works great. Something like:

```
f_regress = functools.partial(f_regression, center=False)
feature_selector = SelectKBest(f_regress, k=k)
```

and then use as normal.